Visual Studio 2022 Azure Function publish profile creation failed
I have created a simple Azure Function triggered by service bus queue messages. It works on my local and I can see the break point hit. However, when I try to publish it to Azure I get this error - Publish profile creation failed.
Here is the Azure Function project which shows this error.
https://github.com/SunnyMittal/Func.ServiceBusMessageProcessor
Any ideas on how to publish Azure Function using Visual Studio?
I have set up Azure service authentication to my user account that has owner permission on the Azure subscription.

Here is the input that I used to provision the Azure function via VS 2022.

It seems to create the Azure resources fine as I can see them created in the Azure portal.

When I try to create a publish profile again same error happens at the end as shown by below steps.







There were multiple credentials in Visual Studio, I removed all of them except the one with the owner privileges in the Azure subscription and then it worked.
It worked with this remaining:


So, the issue is caused by multiple credentials in the visual studio, right? Seems like it was using the wrong credential to publish it. Thanks for sharing it!
